# Why is the text off center from my radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im creating a form with radio buttons. The text next to the radio buttons is on a different level then the buttons.

How can I fix this?

[Website](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/contact.html)

[Screenshot of issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipForm.jpg)

HTML

```
<div class="d5-d8 m-all"id="contactFormContainer" >
                <form name="mainForm" id="mainForm">
                    <p>Getting started or requesting more info?</p>
                    <!--<select name="dropdown">
                        <option value="purchase">Purchase Service</option>
                        <option value="inquire">Get Information</option>
                    </select>-->
                    <input type="radio"  value="Info" name="infoOrPurchase"> Request Info<br>
                    <input type="radio"  value="Purchase" name="infoOrPurchase"> Request Service<br>
                    <br /><br />
                    <label><input type="text" value="First Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='First Name') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'First Name':this.value;" size="35" /></label>
                    <label><input type="text" value="Last Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Last Name') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Last Name':this.value;" size="35" /></label>
                    <label><input type="text" value="Email" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Email':this.value;" /></label>
                    <label><input type="text" value="Phone" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Phone') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Phone':this.value;" /></label>
                    <label><input type="text" value="Company" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Company') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Company':this.value;" /></label>
                    <label><input type="text" value="How did you hear about us?" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value == 'How did you hear about us?') this.value = '';" onblur="    this.value = this.value == '' ? 'How did you hear about us?' : this.value;" /></label>
                    <label><input id="commentsLabel" type="text" value="Comments" size="76" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Comments') this.value = '';" onblur="    this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Comments' : this.value;" /></label>
                </form>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#mainForm{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
}

input{
    height:30px;
}
label{
    margin-top:30px;
}

    #commentsLabel{
        height:80px;
    }


input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(238, 116, 33, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(238, 116, 33, 1);
}
```

Comment: In the future, please use JSFiddle, not screenshots, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I gave the whole site. The screenshot was just another option to view it.

Comment: JSFiddle looks fine to me with the specified CSS and HTML

Comment: Try wrapping the radios in `<span>`s or inline `<div>`s (including the label)

Comment: Howdy, i made you a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/St2Qn/

Comment: @onTheInternet Giving the whole site is also not an acceptable method. Once the problem is fixed, it no longer exists and therefore is useless to visitors in the future. A fiddle will last much longer and provide more information for those who have the same problem as you.

Comment: Makes sense. I will provide a fiddle in the future then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will probably get you closer to what you would like.  Add the following to your CSS.  You can also play around with the value of margin-top if you would like.

```
input[type=radio] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have specified the height. This CSS fixes the issue:

```
input[type=radio]
{
   height:auto;
}
```

Comment: `Height` should **not** be capitalized.

Comment: Dont understand the downvote. This fixed my issue. Will accept as answer when timer allows.

Answer (score 0):

The text is being displayed inline with the radio buttons.  The radio button has a height set, and the button itself wants to orient itself at the center of that total height.  The text sits naturally at the bottom of the line. Adjusting the height of the radio button or playing with them as block elements may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this and it'll be fine:

```
input{
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned (I prefer dgp's response).. defining the 30px height for inputs causes the problem because the label and input aren't vertically aligned.

A couple other things.. clicking on the radio button text should select/deselect the input. To do that give your inputs an id (you can use the same value as 'name') then add a label tag around the text for the radio. the label tag should have a 'for' property that points to the input like in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8SU9/

Note how the first radio button you can click on the text to set the radio.. and clicking the second radio button text does not (I didn't modify the second radio so you could view the difference.)

HTML

```
<div class="d5-d8 m-all"id="contactFormContainer" >
            <form name="mainForm" id="mainForm">
                <p>Getting started or requesting more info?</p>
                <!--<select name="dropdown">
                    <option value="purchase">Purchase Service</option>
                    <option value="inquire">Get Information</option>
                </select>-->
                <input type="radio"  value="Info" name="infoOrPurchase" id="test1"><label for="test1">Request Info</label><br />
                <input type="radio"  value="Purchase" name="infoOrPurchase"> Request Service<br>
                <br /><br />
                <label><input type="text" value="First Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='First Name') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'First Name':this.value;" size="35" /></label>
                <label><input type="text" value="Last Name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Last Name') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Last Name':this.value;" size="35" /></label>
                <label><input type="text" value="Email" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Email':this.value;" /></label>
                <label><input type="text" value="Phone" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Phone') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Phone':this.value;" /></label>
                <label><input type="text" value="Company" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value=='Company') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Company':this.value;" /></label>
                <label><input type="text" value="How did you hear about us?" size="35" onfocus="if (this.value == 'How did you hear about us?') this.value = '';" onblur="    this.value = this.value == '' ? 'How did you hear about us?' : this.value;" /></label>
                <label><input id="commentsLabel" type="text" value="Comments" size="76" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Comments') this.value = '';" onblur="    this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Comments' : this.value;" /></label>
            </form>
        </div>
```